# Adding up values in columns with conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, vba

Being beginner and first time on this site, I truly appreciate your help.

```
WK 1    WK 2    WK 3    WK 4    WK 5    TOTAL HOURS TOTAL OF FIRST 3 WEEKS <> 0
```

John    10  0   5   6   5   26  21

Smith   4   1   10  3   4   22  15

Peter   0   4   4   4   2   14  12

Susan   5   5   0   5   8   23  15

[image: SO23257561 example]

From my table I want to add only the first three columns that contain no zero. If there's zero on first three, check on next column and add it up to complete three columns again with no zero value. Some function like in Col H `TOTAL OF FIRST 3 WEEKS <>0` (where I had to do it manually).

If I can learn set of VB code or any example with formula or macros, thank you so so much. I'm using Excel 2007.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the complicated formula Ali M refers to. It's an [array formula](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/arrayformulas.aspx) entered with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>enter</kbd>:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A2:F2,"<>0")=0,0,SUM(A2:INDEX(A2:F2,SMALL(IF(A2:F2<>0,COLUMN(A2:F2),""),MIN(3,COUNTIF(A2:F2,"<>0"))))))
```

Note that it works if there are less than three non-zero values.

Comment: thanks both of you for your help. Sorry that I couldn't response back to you straight away. I'll be working on it on my study.

Answer (score 1):

you can use formula but it would be complicated. instead you can use this subroutine that act exactly as you want!

```
Public Sub y()
    Dim i, sum, c As Integer

    Dim Rng, Row, cell As Range


    Set Rng = Range("B2:F5")

    i = 0

    For Each Row In Rng.Rows
        For Each cell In Row.Cells
            If (cell.Value <> 0 And i < 3) Then
                sum = sum + cell.Value
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Next cell
        Cells(Row.Row, 7).Value = sum
        sum = 0
        i = 0
    Next Row

 End Sub
```

It always put the sum in column H. you can change it by changing this line:

```
Cells(Row.Row, 7).Value = sum
```

Comment: +1, but note that you are declaring several of your variables as Variants. See this [Chip Pearson page](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DeclaringVariables.aspx) and scroll down to "Pay Attention To Variables Declared With One Dim Statement.

Comment: Thanks Ali, VB code make a lot more easier to understand - going line by line.